# Using Apache Airflow Tool, Implement a DAG for a batch processing pipeline to get a directory from a remote system

Tags: airflow, pysftp

Using Apache airflow tool, how can I implement a DAG for the following Python code. The task accomplished in the code is to get a directory from GPU server to local system. Code is working fine in Jupyter notebook. Please help to implement in Airflow...I'm very new to this. Thanks.

````
import pysftp
import os
myHostname = "hostname"
myUsername = "username"
myPassword = "pwd"

with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword) as sftp:
    print("Connection successfully stablished ... ")
    src = '/path/src/'
    dst = '/home/path/path/destination'
    os.mkdir(dst)
    sftp.get_d(src, dst, preserve_mtime=True)
    print("Fetched source images from GPU server to local directory")
# connection closed automatically at the end of the with-block```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For SFTP duties, Airflow provides [`SFTOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/sftp_operator/index.html) that you can use directly.
- Alternatively it's corresponding [`SFTPHook`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/hooks/sftp_hook.html) can be used with a simple [`PythonOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/python.html)

---

- I acknowledge there aren't many examples, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59639540/3679900) might be helpful
- For SSH-connection, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39494330/3679900)